# Software/app to sync Gmail and Yahoo address books?

Tags: synchronization, contact-manager, gmail, yahoo-mail

I'm looking for an app or software that allows me to sync automatically my Yahoo and Gmail address book.

I need something that allows me to add a contact on Gmail/Yahoo and automatically get that contact on the other provider.

I tried fullcontact but it doesn't support Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [CircleBack](https://www.circleback.com/apps/circleback/)? Syncs with Gmail/Yahoo, available on the web/Android/iPhone, seems to be a good fit.